# Get changed objects from session in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any way to know which objects have been changed since the session? For example, I get a session this way:

```
select *
from v$session
where machine='myMachine'
```

From this I get some information. How I can use this information to know which objects were changed?

Comment: Oracle has a variety of methods to audit changes depending on what "changes" means to you-- are you looking at DDL changes?  DML changes?  Just identifying the object or do you want to know something about the rows that changed?  Unless you've done something to audit changes, Oracle isn't going to track that information automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to know if the procedure of some package has changed.

Comment: More precisely, the body of the procedure

Comment: There is a `last_ddl_time` in `dba_objects` that will tell you the last time there was DDL on the package body (though DDL includes grants).  But that isn't going to tell you anything about which procedure in the package was changed (Oracle doesn't know what you changed within an object) or which session changed it.  But I'm assuming you don't have multiple sessions simultaneously making code changes so the last DDL time might be sufficient.